# react native how to check if Component current show in screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router

In my React native' project i need to check when component is shown in screen to update UI by background thread.

I have look around component props specs and  try `componentWillUnmount`,`componentWillMount` but it not working in my case.

I have try using `navigator.getCurrentRoutes()` too, but it return empty object.

Please help me solve this case!.

Comment: Why componentWillMount/componentWillUnmount won't work? It looks like the right thing to do.

Comment: Can you give more info about your reactNative project? under normal circumstances, componentWillMount is the right thing to do.

Comment: @ManoloSantos i use F8 sample , do log in componentWillMount/componentWillUnmount , but the only thing shown is componentWillMount, after navigate to another screen and back to this screen, nothing happen, i want to check when special component current shown in screen.

Comment: @JeffPChacko componentWillMount working ok, but it happen one times, when i navigate to another screen and current screen hide how can i check component is hidden or shown?

Answer (score 2):

If you use react-navigation you can try useFocusEffect
[useFocusEffect](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-focus-effect/)

But if you don't use it, you can subscribe to the event onLayout of a View. It will trigger whenever your component is mount or your screen's layout change.
[React Native onLayout](https://reactnative.dev/docs/view#onlayout)

Comment: This question was asked 5 years ago. The first commit to the `react-navigation` repo was in 2017, so I doubt OP was using it. He may have been using the alternative by [wix](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation).

Comment: @Moistbobo: Good catch. That said, if this offers solutions to people with a similar problem today, I’m not sure it matters that it wouldn’t have been relevant when the OP originally posed the question.

Comment: @JeremyCaney understandable, thanks for reminding me of the purpose of stackoverflow.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29868686)